# Linear transformation given a Matrix $P_2 \to P_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Question:

[image]

Solution:

[image]

Could someone please explain c and d. I understand a and b. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since $B$ is a basis, you can write any $p=a_0+a_1 x + a_2 x^2 $ uniquely as a linear combination of $\vec v_1, \vec v_2, \vec v_3$. To find the coefficients in terms of $a_0,a_1,a_2$, you need to solve the linear equations:
$$a_0+a_1 x+ a_2 x^2= k_1 \vec v_1 + k_2 \vec v_2 + k_3 \vec v_3$$

And express $k_1,k_2,k_3$ as linear combinations of $a_0,a_1,a_2$. Then you can use part (a) by the fact $$T(a_0+a_1x +a_2x^2)T(k_1 \vec v_1 + k_2 \vec v_2 + k_3 \vec v_3)= k_1 T(\vec v_1) + k_2 T(\vec v_2) + k_3 T(\vec v_3)$$

Then part (d) is just to put in the corresponding coefficients.